# Where is "?" placeholder of sql in play2's anorm

Tags: placeholder, playframework-2.0, anorm

We can write sqls like following in play2's anorm:

```
def findById(id: String): Option[Link] = DB.withConnection {implicit connection =>
  SQL("select * from links where id={id}").on('id -> id).as(simple.singleOpt)
}
```

It uses `{xxx}` format as the placeholder, and the specify a map `'id->id`. Is there anyway to use `?` as the placeholder as we do in play1?

I hope I can write it like:

```
def findById(id:String): Option[Link] = DB.withConnection {implicit connection =>
  SQL("select * from links where id=?").on(id).as(simple.singleOpt)
}
```

This format is very useful sometimes.

Comment: And what is the advantage of using `?` over named parameters?

Comment: Sometimes it's clear enough to use `?` and we can type less

Comment: type less and read less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, currently Anorm uses the Scala symbols for the mapping and you can't use '?'.

This may change in the future, but it is not possible right now.